# Filter all rows having same value in three columns using DataTable.Select

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have three columns in my `Datatable` and I want to filter all the rows where all the three columns do not have the same value.

Currently I am doing it like this

```
dataTable.Select("Col1!=Col2 or Col1!=Col3 or Col2!=Col3");
```

But I am wondering if there is any shortcut way to do this?
Because this approach will grow exponentially if number of columns increases

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check to see whether all items in the [`DataRow.ItemArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.itemarray) are equal using some extension method such as the following:

```
public static partial class DataExtensions
{
    public static bool MultipleItemsAllEqual(this DataRow row)
    {
        // By convention we return false for rows with zero or one item
        var items = row.ItemArray;
        if (items.Length < 2)
            return false;
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<object>.Default;
        return items.Skip(1).All(i => comparer.Equals(i, items[0]));
    }
}
```

Which would be used as follows:

```
var rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => !r.MultipleItemsAllEqual())
    .ToList();
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lnKvzg).

Do note that this approach treats values of different .NET types as different.  Thus an `int` value of `0` and a `double` value of `0.0` will be considered distinct.  For comparison, [`DataTable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select) will attempt to [convert](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/Filter/BinaryNode.cs#L166) values of different types to some identical type before checking for equality.  Failing this, it will throw an exception.  (I.e. if `"Col1"` were of type `string` while `"Col2"` were of type `int` your existing query will throw.)

So if e.g. you want to treat columns with different types as equivalent if they have numeric values with equivalent `double` values, you will have to write your own equality comparer, e.g. like so:

```
public static partial class DataExtensions
{
    public static bool MultipleItemsAllEqual(this DataRow row)
    {
        // By convention we return false for rows with zero or one item
        var items = row.ItemArray;
        if (items.Length < 2)
            return false;
        var first = ToStandardNumericType(items[0]);
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<object>.Default;
        return items.Skip(1).All(i => comparer.Equals(first, ToStandardNumericType(i)));
    }
    
    static object? ToStandardNumericType(this object? value) =>
        IsNumericType(value?.GetType()) ? Convert.ToDouble(value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) : value;

    static bool IsNumericType(this Type? type)
        => Type.GetTypeCode(type) switch
            {
                TypeCode.Byte => true,
                TypeCode.Decimal => true,
                TypeCode.Double => true,
                TypeCode.Int16 => true,
                TypeCode.Int32 => true,
                TypeCode.Int64 => true,
                TypeCode.SByte => true,
                TypeCode.Single => true,
                TypeCode.UInt16 => true,
                TypeCode.UInt32 => true,
                TypeCode.UInt64 => true,
                _ => false,
            };  
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kkXwP4).

Notes:

- Your proposed [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select) query will not work as it uses incorrect syntax for the "not equal" operator.  The [correct syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-8.0#operators) is `<>`:

  ```
  var rows = dataTable.Select("Col1 <> Col2 or Col1 <> Col3 or Col2 <> Col3");
  ```
- Your current approach will not *grow exponentially if number of columns increases*.  However the **complexity of your query string** will grow as `O(nColumns * (nColumns - 1) / 2)` which, while quadratic not exponential, seems very undesirable.  This in turn would seem to make the complexity of the overall query grow as `O(nRows * nColumns * (nColumns - 1) / 2)` which is also undesirable as the algorithm only needs to grow as `O(nRows * nColumns)`.

  That being said, since the `=` operator should be reflexive, symmetric and transitive, you don't really need to check every pair of column values for inequality. You should only need to check that they all don't equal the first column value:

  ```
  var rows = dataTable.Select("NOT(Col1 = Col2 and Col1 = Col3)");
  ```

  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BYJW20).

Answer (score 0):

This basically is about the 'magnitude' of exponential, quadratic, and linear tasks.

If you're asking if you can check all the values of a list without going through every single one AND not having the ability to modify it beforehand then the answer is simply **no**. You must go through every single value of the list.

Unless you're dealing with truly enormous amounts of information there is no real reason to complicate it much because modern computers can handle a lot of information.

Now if you do deal with amounts of information normal computers can't handle easily, and if you're the one who is actually creating the lists (columns of the datatable) and at a later point in time you're checking if they match each other, we are now talking about a mass data handling issue.

There are many ways to tackle this efficiently, depending on the scale of these lists. one solution is adding an extra identifiable row every 50 rows for example which holds the sum for each of the previous 50 rows in the corresponding column. Now when you check the datatable later you can check for every 50 rows if their sum row is identical in all three columns, if so, you can know with absolute certainty if the columns of each row match in case it's of string or char types, and with reasonable certainty if it of double or int types, ('a'+'b' != 'b'+'a', 5+4 = 4+5).

Anyway, that's just one example, there are many more, and looking into security verification of information might help you since it deals with the same problem.

Hopefully, I helped

(;